# Whether PPTP Client need virtual interface to communicate with PPTP Server?

Tags: vpn, networking

We know in PPTP VPN, the VPN Server is using a virtual Interface to provide encrypted data.

Whether PPTP Client need virtual interface to communicate with PPTP Server?

[image]

and more, if yes, whether every kind VPN Client and VPN Server use virtual interface communication?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network. By the way, PPTP is a giant security risk that should never be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a client requires a virtual PPTP interface as well. How that exactly looks depends on the platform/OS and is off topic here.

As Ron has pointed out, PPTP should never be used (alone) for a VPN solution because it is unencrypted and **not private**.

PPTP may still be used to tunnel protocols that are not supported by the tunnel you currently use, like IPX over IPsec, or the network in between. Then you'd create a PPTP tunnel inside your securely encrypted IPsec tunnel or across a private network.